# I want to shuffle an array with a maximum times in a row?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. and one Array comprises  "0"  values and another Array comprises  "1" values. And total value count is 100 in both Arrays. and I want to merge those two arrays into one Array and shuffle values. But without having the same values multiple times in a row(ex - maximum 5 times in the row).

**0 is having six times in a row. But I only want a maximum of five times in a row.**

**ex - 000000100101**

This does not always happen But it happens sometimes. I want to avoid that.

How can I solve this using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Brute force:**

- Merge both arrays of zeroes and ones.
- Keep shuffling this new array until no 0's have a consecutive length more than the maximum count, say `k`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$zeroes = array_fill(0, 10, 0);
$ones = array_fill(0, 10, 1);

function randomize($zeroes, $ones, $maxK){
    $dataSet = array_merge($zeroes, $ones);
    while(true){
        shuffle($dataSet);
        $cnt = 0;
        
        for($i = 0; $i < count($dataSet); ++$i){
            if( $dataSet[ $i ] === 0){
                $cnt++;
                if($cnt > $maxK) break;
            }else{
                $cnt = 0;
            }
            
            if($i === count($dataSet) - 1) return $dataSet;
         }
    }
}

print_r(randomize($zeroes,  $ones, 5));
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/6df91)